# Qt OpenCV - SIGSEGV when displaying transformed frames

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, segmentation-fault

I have an app that has to pull frames from video, transform one a little, transform one a lot, and simultaneously display them in GUI. In a worker thread, there's an OpenCV loop:

```
while(1) {
    cv::VideoCapture kalibrowanyPlik; 
    kalibrowanyPlik.open(kalibracja.toStdString()); //open file from url
    int maxFrames = kalibrowanyPlik.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    for(int i=0; i<maxFrames; i++) //I thought it crashed when finished reading the first time around
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cv::Mat gray;
        cv::Mat color;

        kalibrowanyPlik.read(frame);
        cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::cvtColor(frame, color, CV_BGR2RGB);

        QImage image((uchar*)color.data, color.cols, color.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);
        QImage processedImage((uchar*)gray.data, gray.cols, gray.rows,QImage::Format_Indexed8);

        emit progressChanged(image, processedImage);
        QThread::msleep(50);
    }
}
```

And this is how frames are  placed in GUI

```
void MainWindow::onProgressChagned(QImage image, QImage processedImage) {
    QPixmap processed = QPixmap::fromImage(processedImage);
    processed = processed.scaledToHeight(379);
    ui->labelHsv->clear();
    ui->labelHsv->setPixmap(processed);

    QPixmap original = QPixmap::fromImage(image); //debug points SIGSEGV here
    original = original.scaledToHeight(379);
    ui->labelKalibracja->clear();
    ui->labelKalibracja->setPixmap(original);
}
```

The RGB image always crashes, grayscale image never crashes (tested). Why is the RGB image crashing?

edit: I've just discovered that if I change `msleep(50)` to `msleep(100)` it executes perfectly. But I don't want that. I need at least 25 frames per second, 10 is not acceptable... why would that cause a SIGSEGV

Comment: Impossible to say from what you show us. But the only reasonable location where in this code a segfault can happen is the (uchar*)color.data pointer in QImage image(...). Most likely color.cols, color.rows don't agree with the memory size behind color.data. But this is only a speculation.

Comment: @Greenflow I don't know what more to show you, there is literally nothing else (yet) that does anything with these images

edit: added more info

Comment: Really no much more than I can tell you. Try to comment out  **QImage image((uchar*)color.data, color.cols, color.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);** Does it still crash? You said it crashes only when color is involved. This functions is the only one I see, which uses pointers. So maybe QImage::Format_RGB888 is wrong. Probably your color format is in truth smaller and QImage tries to access data beyond color.data.

Comment: RGB888 must be wrong. I've replaced original with a jpg file and set msleep back to 50, and it loops nicely.

edit: RGB888 is the only one that doesn't crash the app on frame 1

Comment: Frames from video are usually not RGB, or BGR... They are usually in a yuv format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard issue. Problem is memory management!
See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17137998/1387438). In comments there [is a good link](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/).

So in your code `QImage` doesn't copy and doesn't take ownership of memory of matrix. And later on when matrix is destroyed and `QImage` tries access this memory (`QImage` is copied by creating shallow copy)  you have a segfault.

---

Here is a code form [this link](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/) (I've tweak it a bit), for some reason this site has some administration issues (some quota exceeded), that is why I'm pasting it here.

```
inline QImage  cvMatToQImage( const cv::Mat &inMat )
   {
      switch ( inMat.type() )
      {
         // 8-bit, 4 channel
         case CV_8UC4:
         {
            QImage image( inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, inMat.step, QImage::Format_RGB32 );

            QImage copy(image);
            copy.bits(); //enforce deep copy
            return copy;
         }

         // 8-bit, 3 channel
         case CV_8UC3:
         {
            QImage image( inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, inMat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888 );

            return image.rgbSwapped();
         }

         // 8-bit, 1 channel
         case CV_8UC1:
         {
            static QVector<QRgb>  sColorTable;

            // only create our color table once
            if ( sColorTable.isEmpty() )
            {
               for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
                  sColorTable.push_back( qRgb( i, i, i ) );
            }

            QImage image( inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, inMat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8 );
            image.setColorTable( sColorTable );

            QImage copy(image);
            copy.bits(); //enforce deep copy
            return copy;
         }

         default:
            qWarning() << "ASM::cvMatToQImage() - cv::Mat image type not handled in switch:" << inMat.type();
            break;
      }

      return QImage();
   }
```

Your code should utilize this functions like that:

```
while(1) {
    cv::VideoCapture kalibrowanyPlik; 
    kalibrowanyPlik.open(kalibracja.toStdString()); //open file from url
    int maxFrames = kalibrowanyPlik.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    for(int i=0; i<maxFrames; i++) //I thought it crashed when finished reading the first time around
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cv::Mat gray;

        kalibrowanyPlik.read(frame);
        cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        QImage image(cvMatToQImage(frame));
        QImage processedImage(cvMatToQImage(gray));

        emit progressChanged(image, processedImage);
        QThread::msleep(10); // this is bad see comments below
    }
}
```

Use of `msleep` is in 95% cases bad! Remove this loop and create slot which will be invoked by signal from `QTimer`.

Comment: It still crashes when msleep() is set lower than 100

Comment: do it as described in links! Playing around with sleep as synchronization is very bad idea and definitely will not help here. Just copy paste conversion methods and use them.

Comment: The updated version worked like a charm. Thank you! And the suggestion about QTimer might solve my biggest problem yet

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to use a timer :

```
void ??::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*){

 if(kalibrowanssky.isOpened()) 
        cv::Mat frame;
        cv::Mat gray;
        cv::Mat color;

        kalibrowanyPlik.read(frame);
        cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::cvtColor(frame, color, CV_BGR2RGB);

        ui->labelHsv->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Mat2QImage(color)));
        ui->labelKalibracja->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Mat2QImage(gray)));
}
```

In your main :

```
cv::VideoCapture kalibrowanyPlik; 
startTimer(1000/25); // 25 frames by second
```

And the function Mat2QImage (I found it here : [how to convert an opencv cv::Mat to qimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage/8866986#8866986)) :

```
QImage ??::Mat2QImage(cv::Mat const& src) {

     cv::Mat temp; 
     cvtColor(src, temp,CV_BGR2RGB); 
     QImage dest((const uchar *) temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
     dest.bits();

     return dest;
}
```