# QGraphicsScene paint event inside QGraphicsProxyWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qgraphicsscene, paintevent

I am streaming from a webcam using OpenCV. Each captured frame (type is `cv::Mat`) is transported via custom signal to slots in a node-based `QGraphicsScene`. Since I have a single type of node that actually requires to display the `cv::Mat` while the rest is just for processing the data I have created a **viewer** widget that converts the `cv::Mat` data to `QImage` data and then using `paintEvent()` draws it on its surface:

[image: Node-based QGraphicsScene - intenral paint events]

Here is the code for the widget itself:

**qcvn_node_viewer.hpp**

```
#ifndef QCVN_NODE_VIEWER_HPP
#define QCVN_NODE_VIEWER_HPP

#include <QWidget>
#include <QImage>
#include <QSize>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

class QCVN_Node_Viewer : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QImage output;

  public:
    explicit QCVN_Node_Viewer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QCVN_Node_Viewer();

    QSize sizeHint() const;
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;

    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17137998/1559401
    static QImage Mat2QImage(cv::Mat const& frame);
    static cv::Mat QImage2Mat(QImage const& src);

  protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

  signals:
    // Nodes connect to sendFrame(cv::Mat) signal
    void sendFrame(cv::Mat);

  public slots:
    void receiveFrame(cv::Mat frame);
};

#endif // QCVN_NODE_VIEWER_HPP
```

**qcvn_node_viewer.cpp**

```
#include "qcvn_node_viewer.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <QPainter>

QCVN_Node_Viewer::QCVN_Node_Viewer(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent)
{
  qRegisterMetaType<cv::Mat>("cv::Mat");
}

QCVN_Node_Viewer::~QCVN_Node_Viewer()
{
}

QSize QCVN_Node_Viewer::sizeHint() const
{
  return output.size();
}

QSize QCVN_Node_Viewer::minimumSizeHint() const
{
  return output.size();
}

QImage QCVN_Node_Viewer::Mat2QImage(cv::Mat const& frame)
{
     cv::Mat temp;
     cvtColor(frame, temp,CV_BGR2RGB);
     QImage dest((const uchar *) temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
     dest.bits(); // enforce deep copy
     return dest;
}

cv::Mat QCVN_Node_Viewer::QImage2Mat(QImage const& frame)
{
     cv::Mat tmp(frame.height(),frame.width(),CV_8UC3,(uchar*)frame.bits(),frame.bytesPerLine());
     cv::Mat result; // deep copy just in case (my lack of knowledge with open cv)
     cvtColor(tmp, result,CV_BGR2RGB);
     return result;
}

void QCVN_Node_Viewer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0), output);
  painter.end();
}

void QCVN_Node_Viewer::receiveFrame(cv::Mat frame)
{
  if(frame.empty()) return;

  // Pass along the received frame
  emit sendFrame(frame);

  // Generate
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127762/cvmat-to-qimage-and-back
  // Applications crashes sometimes! Conversion seems to be incorrect
  output = Mat2QImage(frame);
  output.bits();
  setFixedSize(output.width(), output.height());

  repaint();
}
```

As you can see from the screenshot above the `QWidget` is embedded in a `QGraphicsScene` using `QGraphicsProxyWidget` along with a `QGraphicsRectItem` that I use for selecting/moving the node around in the scene.

Using `QPainter` is considered to be more efficient than using `QLabel` and settings its `QPixmap` to the captured and converted frame. Using an OpenGL viewport inside a `QGraphicsScene` as far as I know is not an option. It seems that processing the paint events in the scene also handles the local ones inside the `QGraphicsItem`s and `QGraphicsProxyWidget`s. The frame that the **viewer** paints on its surface changes **only** when the scene's paint event handler is called (hovering some of my nodes, moving them around etc.).

Is there a way to fix this? I'm about to go for the `QLabel+QPixmap` option (even though I'm not sure if it won't suffer from the same or different problem) but first I'd like to make sure there is nothing I can do to keep my current way of doing things.

---

**EDIT:** Okay, so I have changed my viewer to use `QLabel` instead of the widget's paint event and it works like a charm. The question is still opened though since I'd like to know how to use local paint events.

Comment: I suspect the receiveFrame() method should be calling update() rather than repaint()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually first tried using `update()` but I got basically the same poor results as `repaint()`. Also `repaint()` as far as I know immediately invokes the paint event while `update()` doesn't.