# Displaying opencv Mat image into QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I use these lines of codes to display the Mat image in a graphicsView in Qt:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(image.data,image.cols, image.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888)));
```

But the image is displayed with a blue mask over it.
And the Mat image is shown correctly, when I try to display it with this code:

```
imshow("image", image);
```

I don't understand where is the bug.

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR color format, not RGB as your code seems to assume. Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: Exactly BGR vs RGB issue. Just call "cvtColor(image, image, COLOR_BGR2RGB);" before creating the QImage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17137998/1387438

Comment: I already did the transformation with cvtColor, but the result remains the same.

Comment: @MarekR: That solved my problem. Thanks.