# How can I represent colormap data in QwT from cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, colormap, qwt

I'm developing an application in c++ with Qt and Qwt framework for scientific plots. I have matrix data stored as `cv::Mat`, representing an image with scalar data (MxN), which needs to be visualized as a colormap.

With OpenCV it is performed using `cv::applyColorMap(img,cm_img,cv::COLORMAP_JET)` and `cv::imshow("img name", img)`, as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html)

I have tried converting `cv::Mat` to `QImage`, as described [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=cv%3A%3AMat+qimage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127762/cvmat-to-qimage-and-back/17137998) but it seems not to be working properly. When I try to show the resulting images, it doesn't make sense.

From Qwt, there are some classes that looks interesting for that matter: [QwtMatrixRasterData](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_matrix_raster_data.html), [QwtPlotSpectrogram](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_spectrogram.html) or [QwtPlotRasterItem](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_raster_item.html).

What I need as final output would be something like this.
Given a matrix (MxN) with double values, calling something like imshow I get an colormap image like this

[image: colormap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came around using [QCustomPlot](https://www.qcustomplot.com/), sending it a `QVector<double>`.

The idea is to create the `QVector` from `cv::Mat`:

```cpp
QVector<double> cvMatToQVector(const cv::Mat& mat) {
  QVector<double> image;
  auto img_ptr = img.begin<double>();

  for (; img_ptr < img.end(); img_ptr++) {
    image.append(*img_ptr) = element;
  }
  return image;
}
```

Then we create a `QCPColorMap* colorMap` and populate it with `QVector vec` data:

```cpp
  for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < col; ++yIndex) {
    y_col = yIndex * col;
    for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < row; ++xIndex) {
      z = vec.at(xIndex + y_col);
      colorMap->data()->setCell(xIndex, yIndex, z);
    }
  }
```